# Reducing a Laplace Matrix which is also Scalar?

Tags: matrices

I had a 9x9 matrix as follows: Aim is to reduce it to Lower or Upper Matrix

```
[ 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1,  8,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1,  0,  8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1,  8,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1,  0,  8, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  8,  0, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  8, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  8,  0]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  8]
```

Let rows and column be numbered from 0 to 8.

After performing

- R2*(-1) Add to R1
- R4*(-1) Add to R3
- R6*(-1) Add to R5
- R8*(-1) Add to R7

I got

```
[8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[0,  8, -8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[-1, 0,  8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[0,  0,  0,  8, -8,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[-1,-1, -1,  0,  8, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[ 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  8, -8,  0,  0]
[-1,-1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  8, -1, -1]
[ 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8, -8]
[-1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  8]
```

After performing

- R2*(-1) Add to R0
- R4*(-1) Add to R2
- R6*(-1) Add to R4
- R8*(-1) Add to R6

Now we have:

```
[ 9, -1, -9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[ 0,  8, -8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[ 0,  1,  9, -1, -9,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[ 0,  0,  0,  8, -8,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  9, -1, -9,  0,  0]
[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8, -8,  0,  0]
[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  9, -1, -9]
[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8, -8]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  8]
```

After this I could not proceed, I tried but it became messi :( Is it possible to reach our aim from here? Or we should start from beginning in a completely different way?

Answer (score 0):

There are standard methods (and not so creative, as presented by you :-) ) for such the matrix reductions. For instance, Gauss method reduces a matrix over a field $\mathbb R$ or a method based on Euclid algorithm (for finding the greatest common divisor) reduces a matrix over a ring $\mathbb Z$. Both these methods are well-known, so you should easily find them in Internet.

Comment: oh..okay. Actually I was also aiming at how quickly can I do it. Now I remember, when we studied this in 10+2 Grade, we were taught Gauss-Jordan Elimination Method. But we normally dealt questions by performing such naive or (creative ;-) ) Row-Column Operations, so I was trying that way. Well, thanks for making me remember GJ method.